# PHP & MySQL - Deleting users problem

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason if a user does not have data in the info or pid MySQL tables I can't delete the user form any other table like the user table is there some way I can have the user 
deleted even if the user has not entered data into the other tables except the user table?

Here is part of the code for deleting members.

```
    if(($months >= 3) && ($row['deletion'] == 1)){


        $dqc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM info WHERE user_id = '" . $row['user_id'] . "'");
        if(!$dqc){ print mysqli_error($mysqli); }

        $dpq = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM pid WHERE user_id = '" . $row['user_id'] . "'");
        if(!$dpq){ print mysqli_error($mysqli); }

        $duq = mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '" . $row['user_id'] . "'");
        if(!$duq){ print mysqli_error($mysqli); }
    }
```

Comment: Is your table really called `p`?

Comment: Where is the code that is populating `$row['user_id']`?

Comment: You could cascade delete from users, letting the sub-tables take care of themselves.

Comment: Does it print anything? Anything in the error log?

Comment: @webbiedave I did not include it but its there.

Comment: Considering webbiedave's question, you may want to store $row['user_id'] in another variable first so you don't accidentally remove that information before the user_id has been removed from all tables. But I'm not sure how this function works entirely as this is just a short excerpt. This may be irrelevant.

Comment: @Ben what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @KoolMoeD, If you have a user ID that relates to each of the other tables, you can set up in the DBMS a "cascade delete" option.  With this enabled, submitting a delete to the primary user table will automatically delete related records out of the sub tables without you doing any extra work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have some dependency issues regarding foreign key constraints. What are the relationships like between the user, info and pid tables? Depending on the relationships you may want to re-order your delete statements.

Comment: They have no relations, I'm just checking if a user has created a table using there `user_id` from the user table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is populating properly

```
 $row['user_id']
```